# How can I import my Ubuntu terminal's color scheme for a different computers?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, zsh, themes

I did a reinstall on my computer presently, and I want to restore my previous terminal settings. While exporting my settings, I ran the command

```
 gconftool-2 --dump '/apps/gnome-terminal' > gnome-terminal-conf.xml
```

Now running the following restore command on my Ubuntu 15.04 machine does nothing. Can anyone give me any pointers how to overcome this?

```
gconftool-2 --load terminal-color-scheme.xml
```

My gnome-terminal version is **3.14.2** and I am running zsh over it, using the very popular **oh-my-zsh**. Also, is there a tool that I can use to export and import without all this hassle in the future?

Comment: Same problem [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/668227/148451)! Any ideas?

Comment: I guess I figured and answered my own question there :)